# machine learning model based on tidymodels package seems calculate metrics incorrectly

Tags: r, machine-learning, tidymodels

I have simulated data as follows:

```
require(tidymodels)

set.seed(123)
x1=rnorm(1000,0,1)
x2=rnorm(1000,0.5,1)
x3=rnorm(1000,2.5,1)
x4=rnorm(1000,2.5,1.5)

y=exp(0.3*x1 + 0.25*x2 + 0.75)/(1+exp(0.3*x1 + 0.25*x2 + 0.75))
y_bin=ifelse(y>0.8,1,0)


data_sim=data.frame(x1,x2=2.5*x2,x3=3*x3, x4,y_bin=factor(y_bin))
```

Based on this data, I fitted following lasso logistic regression model using 5-fold cross validation

```
set.seed(123)
fold_data=vfold_cv(data_sim,v=5)

lasso_spec<- logistic_reg( penalty = tune(),
                           mixture = 1) %>% set_engine("glmnet")

lamd_grid <- grid_regular(penalty(), levels =50)

res_basic <- recipe(y_bin ~ x1 +x2+x3 + x4  , data=data_sim)

wf <- workflow() %>% add_model(lasso_spec) %>% add_recipe(res_basic)

lasso_tune <- wf %>%
              tune_grid(
                resamples=fold_data,
                grid=lamd_grid,
                control=control_grid(verbose = FALSE, save_pred = T),
                metrics=metric_set(roc_auc, sensitivity, precision, recall)
                
              )
```

The best model based on precision metric as following values:

```
lasso_tune %>% show_best("precision")
# A tibble: 5 × 7
   penalty .metric   .estimator  mean     n std_err .config              
     <dbl> <chr>     <chr>      <dbl> <int>   <dbl> <chr>                
1 1   e-10 precision binary     0.997     5 0.00138 Preprocessor1_Model01
2 1.60e-10 precision binary     0.997     5 0.00138 Preprocessor1_Model02
3 2.56e-10 precision binary     0.997     5 0.00138 Preprocessor1_Model03
4 4.09e-10 precision binary     0.997     5 0.00138 Preprocessor1_Model04
5 6.55e-10 precision binary     0.997     5 0.00138 Preprocessor1_Model05
```

At the mean time, I extracted the predictions from each fold as follows:

```
fod1=lasso_tune$.predictions[[1]] %>% filter(penalty %in% p1$penalty) %>% 
      select(.pred_class, y_bin)

fod2=lasso_tune$.predictions[[2]] %>% filter(penalty %in% p1$penalty) %>% 
  select(.pred_class, y_bin)

fod3=lasso_tune$.predictions[[3]] %>% filter(penalty %in% p1$penalty) %>% 
  select(.pred_class, y_bin)

fod4=lasso_tune$.predictions[[4]] %>% filter(penalty %in% p1$penalty) %>% 
  select(.pred_class, y_bin)

fod5=lasso_tune$.predictions[[5]] %>% filter(penalty %in% p1$penalty) %>% 
  select(.pred_class, y_bin)

fold_cmb=data.frame(rbind(fod1,fod2,fod3,fod4,fod5))
```

The cross tabulation based on combine results looks like this:

```
> table(fold_cmb$.pred_class,fold_cmb$y_bin)
   
      0   1
  0 885   3
  1   1 111
```

Based on this precision should be equal to 0.991, not 0.997.
I guess the package calculate the precision for wrong class label. You can see that for y_bin=0, 885/888=0.997.

So, Can anyone help me to figure out how to change the code so that it will calculate the metrics correctly? Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting that results because `precision()`, and all the other {yardstick} metrics uses the first level as the "event". Thus `0` is considered the event for your data due to the construction of your data.

To get the results you want you can:

## Set levels at the beginning

Using the `levels` argument in `factor` you can specify which level be the first and thus be considered the "event" by {yardstick}.

Doing this

```r
factor(y_bin, levels = c(1, 0))
```

instead of this

```r
factor(y_bin)
```

## Use the `event_level` argument

The metric functions that are affected by level ordering have an argument `event_level` that you can use to specify how the calculations should be done

```r
library(yardstick)

# event_level defaults to "first"
two_class_example |>
  precision(truth = truth, estimate = predicted)
#> # A tibble: 1 × 3
#>   .metric   .estimator .estimate
#>   <chr>     <chr>          <dbl>
#> 1 precision binary         0.819

two_class_example |>
  precision(truth = truth, estimate = predicted, event_level = "second")
#> # A tibble: 1 × 3
#>   .metric   .estimator .estimate
#>   <chr>     <chr>          <dbl>
#> 1 precision binary         0.861
```

The `control_grid()` function also has this argument so you can get the results when running {tune} functions

Do this

```r
control_grid(verbose = FALSE, save_pred = T, event_level = "second")
```